# Accessing Development Server Remotely

Tags: networking, ubuntu, mailman

I've successfully installed mailman version 3 on my development box. I configured it and having it running to my liking. I have installed it exactly the same on a stage box. (Both are ubuntu 14.04).

My question doesn't lie in the installation, but rather accessing the location.
There is a user interface that is accessable by default at localhost:8000.

To start the server at its default location I would run:

```
./bin/mailman-web-django-admin runserver &
```

And when I use my development box, I would grab the IP of my webserver and start the server there to access the UI of the application running on my VM from my laptop.

```
./bin/mailman-web-django-admin runserver 192.168.xx.xx:8000 &
```

My question is how would I access my server remotely at its 55.xx.xx.xx public IP?
When I try to access 55.xx.xx.xx:8000 after starting the webserver at localhost I get: "This weppage is not available." and the connection times out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please for the love of everything holy, don't open up this port to the Internet generally. If you do this, any vulnerability in the admin tool will result in your system being compromised and, most likely, being used to attack other computers.

Instead, just use ssh. Either connect to your server and run a browser that way, or use ssh to open up the port 8000 to your local machine, securely.

[This article](http://blog.trackets.com/2014/05/17/ssh-tunnel-local-and-remote-port-forwarding-explained-with-examples.html) explains how to do ssh tunnels. In your case, you can probably just do:

```
ssh -L 8000:your.server.com:8000 youruser@your.server.com
```

and then you can just open your browser and point to localhost:8000 to access the configuration tool.

Comment: You're right, I never realized I could connect through SSH to a web browser. I've always done it from command line to command line so i never connected the dots in that fashion. Thanks for your reply, sorry for the length in the response, I went to use the SSH and it dawned on me to get back to you. Cheers!